# Connect Arduino Mega to Firebase

Tags: firebase, arduino, include, arduino-esp8266

I have an Arduino Mega 2560 board and an ESP8266 WiFi Module. I need to connect my Arduino board to my Firebase database, so I can get data from my database to the Arduino.

When I include the `<FirebaseArduino.h>` library, there is an error saying

> Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560

Isn't it possible to connect an Arduino Mega board to Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add ESP8266.h header file to the project.